# Request scoped ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` impl e.g. `HeaderRequestFilter`, i want to make it to be instantiated for every request. I am using spring and jersey. I tried putting `@Scope("request")` on top of `HeaderRequestFilter` but it is getting instantiated once i.e. singleton. i want to maintain states like `javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo`, `javax.ws.rs.core.Request`. so if the class is singleton then it will be subjected to race conditions.

Could somebody help me resolving this? Thanks.

Comment: Are those implementations of `Filter`, managed by the Servlet container?

Comment: javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: Can you explain why you need it to be instantiated per-request?

Answer (score 2):

From the [JAX-RS specification, 6.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf):

> By default, just like all the other providers, a single instance of
>   each filter or entity interceptor is instantiated for each JAX-RS
>   application. (...) Implementations MAY offer alternative lifecycle
>   options beyond the default one.

I don't know if any implementation is providing a different lifecycle.

You don't need to fear race conditions when e.g. injecting the `HttpServletRequest` via `@Context`. The spec clearly points out in Chapter 9.1:

> Context is specific to a particular request but instances of certain
>   JAX-RS components (providers and resource classes with a lifecycle
>   other than per-request) may need to support multiple concurrent
>   requests. When injecting an instance of one of the types listed in
>   Section 9.2, the instance supplied MUST be capable of selecting the
>   correct context for a particular request. Use of a thread-local proxy
>   is a common way to achieve this.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. i want to maintain states like javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo, javax.ws.rs.core.Request. so if the class is singleton then it will be subjected to race conditions.

Comment: @lefloh What happens when injecting with \@Inject instead of \@Context ?

Comment: Why would you want to?